# Reuse FROM clause from One query in Other query (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Question:

I am writing a SELECT query whose FROM clause contains nested query and fetches data from multiple queries. I need to use the data from FROM cluase again in several other queries.

What is the best way to do that in Oracle.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to reuse a query in multiple distinct SQL statements, the simplest option is to create a view for that SQL statement

```
CREATE VIEW view_name
AS
  <<query to reuse>>
```

and then use that view in all your queries.

If you need to reuse a query in multiple places in the same SQL statement, use subquery factoring and the `WITH` clause

```
WITH query_name AS (
  <<query to reuse>>
)
SELECT *
  FROM query_name q1
 WHERE something = (select max(something)
                      from query_name q2
                     where q1.key = q2.key)
```